# Is the time stamp for posted answers actually accurate to the millisecond?

Tags: discussion

There is a question with two answers from two different users that have the same time stamp:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/318494/79975

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/318493/79975

Is the time stamp actually accurate to the millisecond?

Comment: The displayed timestamp only has a precision of 1 second. Why would you expect millisecond accuracy?

Comment: If you ain't first, you're last.   ;)

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, millisecond values exist, but are not shown directly on the site**

Using Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), I've written a [small query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/726077/playing-with-dates) to demonstrate that the millisecond value exists. The 'CreatedDate' field will not show this by default, but by `CONVERT()`ing the field and using [the '114' datetime style](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) (`hh:mi:ss:mmm`) we can see the milliseconds:

[image: Example returned values]

Do note that the data displayed on SEDE is only refreshed once a week, so your example answers won't appear until next Monday. We'll have to [wait and see](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/726089/who-won?QuestionId=318491) what the milliseconds look like. Note however, that based on the Answer IDs in your above links:

- **318493** - Timmy Jim
- **318494** - Avery

Timmy Jim was 'first' :)

Comment: Alright, [the SEDE numbers are here](https://s.ave.zone/1a92.png). Timmy Jim's answer preceded mine by merely 44 msecs. That's crazy.